# Пул обёрток над примитивами

Tags: java

Значения входящие в диапазон [-128; 127], у оберток на примитивами хранятся не напрямую в хипе, а в неком пуле для более быстрого доступа к ним. Как по отношению к хипу располагается этот пул(является ли пул частью хипа)? + На сколько я понимаю похожая ситуация и с пулов String-ов

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Судя по коду, кеш-интов, это обычный Integer массив, который заполняется статическим блоком :

```
private static class IntegerCache {
        static final int low = -128;
        static final int high;
        static final Integer cache[];

        static {
            // high value may be configured by property
            int h = 127;
            String integerCacheHighPropValue =
                sun.misc.VM.getSavedProperty("java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high");
            if (integerCacheHighPropValue != null) {
                try {
                    int i = parseInt(integerCacheHighPropValue);
                    i = Math.max(i, 127);
                    // Maximum array size is Integer.MAX_VALUE
                    h = Math.min(i, Integer.MAX_VALUE - (-low) -1);
                } catch( NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    // If the property cannot be parsed into an int, ignore it.
                }
            }
            high = h;

            cache = new Integer[(high - low) + 1];
            int j = low;
            for(int k = 0; k < cache.length; k++)
                cache[k] = new Integer(j++);

            // range [-128, 127] must be interned (JLS7 5.1.7)
            assert IntegerCache.high >= 127;
        }
```

Поэтому он хранится в хипе.